# update activity with new values in Android

Tags: php, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity which display values in list view. These values are returned from MYSQL in cloud.  I need to refresh the activity so if new value inserted in MYSQL DB the activity display the new values immediately if the activity is currently opened by the user.
By the way, I am using a PHP code to retrieve the data from MYSQL to android activity.

Answer (score 0):

- Call your webservice again
- On successful result, clear listview's current adapter
- Fill the adapter with new data
- Call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Refresh the listview

Answer (score 0):

You should notify your array adapter when you update your list with the values coming from your server. So, call `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you make any changes in your list. In this case, call it when you add new values to the list.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways but I have created like this,
1 - get last id of last item and save it as currentLastId
2 - create an other service in php which send last id of element as updatedLastId
3 - create a background service which always call that webservice in background
4 - than compare if(currentLastId < updatedLastId) { call your webservice and   reset your list }
5 - notify your list